# How to listen active dragging event of an UWP UIElement?

Tags: xaml, events, uwp

How to track/listen active dragging event of UI Element in UWP. I added the flat `CanDrag=true` to enable the drag feature. Using the `DragStarting` and `DragLeave` can identify the start and end of drag. But want to get the X,Y coordinate of the UIElement on dragging. ***Any recommendation*** to achieve that? I dont want to use `RenderTransform` for this.

Comment: At what point do you want to retrive the coordinates? At the start, end or during dragging?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in standard Drag'n'Drop flow.
There're few options but they look like a crutch.

1. You may use manipulations and subscribe to Delta event. That's where RenderTransform comes in.
2. You may start some time loop and get visual position each frame. (The most crutchy idea)
3. Try to play wih IsHitTestVisible and subscribe to PointMove of some FrameworkElement behind.
4. Subscribe to PointEntered and PointExited to the elements you dragging over so they could fire events.

I prefer the first one. It's simple and it's plane.